# Output String Array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print some values on a string like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;    
data.push_back("One");
data.push_back("1");
const std::string & description = "This %s is number %s";

DWORD dwSize = data.size();

char szDescription[255 + 1];

for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwSize; ++i)
{
    _snprintf(szDescription, sizeof(szDescription), description.c_str(), data[i].c_str());
}

return szDescription;
```

However, when I print the string it returns me:

```
This One is number 124897566
```

I print the strings after `snprintf` and the second value is handled on the first iteration

Comment: `_snprintf()`  and `char[]` mixed with `std::string`? Just... *why*?

Comment: Not used to work with strings and characters in C++, illuminate me if you can

Comment: A `C` function such as `_snprintf()` knows nothing about objects, yet you are sending to `_snprintf()` a `std::string`.  You're lucky you got as far as anything being printed, instead of a crash.

Comment: In addition, your code cannot be used safely in a multithreaded program.  That static array is just not going to work too well.

Comment: I edited the code, however the result is just another number

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'd say a crash would have been the luckier result.

Comment: @MiguelSilva Why are you using `_snprintf()` at all? Sounds like an XY-problem for me?

Comment: You're referencing a variable called `value` that you never declare or assign a value to.  That and several other things make me think you boiled your code down too much for this post.

Comment: [Get a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)...

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Say "unlucky", rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution for you is to replace the tokens in the `std::string` one by one. There are different solutions you could use (e.g., using regular expressions, using a library like [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), etc.). Here is a simple example that uses basic `std::string` methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string build() {
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    data.push_back("One");
    data.push_back("1");

    const std::string token = "%s";
    const std::string description = "This %s is number %s";

    std::string out = "";
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = description.find(token);
    int i = 0;
    while (end != std::string::npos) {
        out += description.substr(start, end - start);
        out += data[i++];
        start = end + token.length();
        end = description.find(token, start);
    }
    out += description.substr(start, end - start);

    return out;
}   

int main () {
    std::cout << build() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints:

```
This One is number 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, you can use [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).  The issue with `_snprintf` is that it is not type-safe (the input type must match the format specifier), and that it knows nothing about C++ objects such as `std::string`.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::string foo()
{
   std::vector<std::string> data;    
   data.push_back("One");
   data.push_back("1");
   std::ostringstream strm;
   std::string s;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
   {
      strm << "The " << data[i] << " is number " << i + 1;
      s = strm.str();
      std::cout << s << "\n";
      strm.str(""); 
   }
   return s;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Output:

```
The One is number 1
The 1 is number 2
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/8CIWRG)

Comment: Thank you for the string example but still doesn't reach the point of the question, the objective is to iterate for each value in the vector and format while format string appear, like %s, %d, etc..
@HugoTeixeira gave me the correct response till now

Comment: Your original question is not worded correctly or is not sufficient.  There is no mention of the importance of keeping the format string.  You are trying to hold onto `C` concepts, and the answer given is basically how to let go of those concepts.  Also, look at the output produced in this answer and in the one given by HugoTeixera -- what is the difference?

Comment: Sorry i was quite sleepy, the objective is to format, not concatenate, assuming that the string and value is given by a text script that is parsed, thats why his example works for the question, however if there is a solution with `ostringstream` it would be better, without doing the splitting of course